# How can i change the colour of a component in JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, colors, jframe

Here's my code:

```
public class JavaApplication7 extends JPanel
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JPanel pan = new JPanel();
        JFrame frm = new JFrame();
        frm.add(new JavaApplication7());
        frm.setSize(500, 500);
        frm.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        frm.setForeground(Color.red);
        frm.setVisible(true);
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pan.setSize(768,512);
        pan.setVisible(true);
    }
    public void paintComponent (Graphics g){
        g.drawOval(50, 50, 50, 50);
        g.setColor(Color.CYAN);       
    }
}
```

I want the Oval to change color but when I run my program it remains black instead of cyan that I want.

Comment: Dont forget to call `super.paintComponent` as first call in overriden `paintComponent` method or else guarenteed you will be posting about visual anomalies next :P Also dont forget to create and manipulate Swing components on EDT via `SwingUtilities.invokeXXX` block

Comment: @DavidKroukamp Firstly thanks for the advice.Although if i put super.paintComponent() then the background colour disappears how can i overcome this problem ?

Comment: Draw the background color to the graphics object i.e `g.setColor(Color.red); g.fillRect(0,0,getWidth(),getHeight());`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You first draw the oval and then change the color. That's why you don't see the effect.
Just change the order of statements:

```
g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
g.drawOval(50, 50, 50, 50);
```